# Cannot access Neo4j container with Neomodel

Tags: docker, neo4j, docker-compose, neomodel

I have 2 different containers running with docker-compose. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    #Create backend container
    backend:
        build: ./backend # path to Dockerfile
        ports: # Port binding to host from docker container
            - "5000:5000"
        container_name: buzzworks-backend
        volumes: 
            - ${PWD}/backend:/app
        depends_on: 
            - db
        environment: 
            FLASK_APP: flaskr
            FLASK_ENV: development
            NEO_USER: ${NEO_USER}
            NEO_PW: ${NEO_PW}
    
    db:
        image: neo4j:4.1.1
        container_name: buzzworks-neo4j
        ports:
            - "7474:7474"
            - "7687:7687"
        volumes:
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/data:/data
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/logs:/logs
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
        environment:
            NEO4J_AUTH: ${NEO_USER}/${NEO_PW}
            NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: ${NEO_DEBUG_LEVEL}
```

The corresponding network it generates looks right to me:

```
    {
        "Name": "buzzworksai_default",
        "Id": "db4efc0286a9464cadde13cf1306f241b7a353295904b15b163e761289ba9d3f",
        "Created": "2020-08-27T11:23:15.925483629-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "640650c163f746e480bf677abdeaf8edf6483b7dac2a260c2e3b3bc3319dffef": {
                "Name": "buzzworks-neo4j",
                "EndpointID": "ddbad1a179cc51655a779b07c91d6d949b0612bf985abc9c45e1794b35f4a565",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ba47173d1dbc31e4e416eaf30d2314e6d2a20a36b389cb76cd1edcbea489184e": {
                "Name": "buzzworks-backend",
                "EndpointID": "17ff278f3db5ad609be682cdf912ca755587e07ef08d6023bf3ecb33a6c4bc31",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "buzzworksai",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.26.2"
        }
    }
]
```

I can access the web interface of the neo4j database just fine. The problem occurs when I am trying to connect to the database with `neomodel`. I have tried running `neomodel_remove_labels --db bolt://<user>:<password>@db:7687` with the appropriate credentials from the shell of the python container. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/neomodel_remove_labels", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/neomodel_remove_labels", line 30, in main
    db.set_connection(bolt_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neomodel/util.py", line 93, in set_connection
    self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver(u.scheme + '://' + hostname,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 108, in driver
    return Driver(uri, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 147, in __new__
    return subclass(uri, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 221, in __new__
    pool.release(pool.acquire())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 715, in acquire
    return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 608, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 218, in connector
    return connect(address, **dict(config, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 972, in connect
    raise last_error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 963, in connect
    s, der_encoded_server_certificate = _secure(s, host, security_plan.ssl_context, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 854, in _secure
    s = ssl_context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host if HAS_SNI and host else None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

I have tried to access the container from my host with `bolt://<user>:<password>@localhost:7687` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be your issue which is related to neo4j: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12392

The suggestion there is:

> Neo4j 4.0 has encryption turned off by default. You need to explicitly
> turn encryption back on for Bolt server in server config file. Then
> you shall be able to connect using 1.7 python driver with default
> settings.
>
> The following is an example of how you can turn encryption back on
> Bolt Server with private.key and public.crt in directory
> $neo4jHome/certificates/bolt.
>
> ```
> dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
>
> # allows both encrypted and unencrypted driver connections
> dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
>
> dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled=true
> dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.base_directory=certificates/bolt
> #dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.private_key=private.key
> #dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.public_certificate=public.crt
> ```
>
> You can choose any trusted key and certificate service to generate the
> private key and public certificate used here.

Comment: Where is `neo4jHome`? Is that the $HOME directory inside the neo4j container?
EDIT: Sorry, should've tried it first. Yes it is.
EDIT2: But, I don't see any `bolt` directory inside `certificates/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `network` option on your docker-compose file. Please read this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) and then you will understand it well.

You should do something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    #Create backend container
    backend:
        build: ./backend # path to Dockerfile
        ports: # Port binding to host from docker container
            - "5000:5000"
        container_name: buzzworks-backend
        volumes: 
            - ${PWD}/backend:/app
        depends_on: 
            - db
        environment: 
            FLASK_APP: flaskr
            FLASK_ENV: development
            NEO_USER: ${NEO_USER}
            NEO_PW: ${NEO_PW}
        networks:
            - mynetwork
    
    db:
        image: neo4j:4.1.1
        container_name: buzzworks-neo4j
        ports:
            - "7474:7474"
            - "7687:7687"
        volumes:
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/data:/data
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/logs:/logs
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import
            - ${HOME}/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
        environment:
            NEO4J_AUTH: ${NEO_USER}/${NEO_PW}
            NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: ${NEO_DEBUG_LEVEL}
        networks:
            - mynetwork

networks:
    mynetwork:
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue and I'm not sure why it would. From my understanding, the network option allows you to custom config your docker-compose network, but why do you need to? Docker-compose already creates a network, called `buzzworksai_default` in my case,  and both of my containers are a part of it, as shown in the json in my original question. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding.